# Add table description to iceberg table from pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive, apache-iceberg

I was able to add a table comment to an iceberg table using trino, with this trino command:

```
comment on table iceberg.table_schema.table_name is 'My Comment'
```

Also It is possible to read that from pyspark using:

```
spark.sql("describe extended iceberg.table_schema.table_name")
```

I couldn't find a way to insert these comments to the table using spark.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I found out a way to do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE catalog.schema.table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES('comment'='a comment')
```

But I would still like to do that through saveAsTable if possible.